# Blocked traffic by htaccess but now server itself can't acces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having a website which runs it's CMS from a subdomain. The CMS is protected by a password, but since my company has a fixed IP, I also want to block everyone who is not accessing the CMS from within the company.

So I added the following to my .htaccess file at the subdomain:

```
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Deny from all
```

1.2.3.4 is my fake fixed company IP

This is working fine, but I'm running scripts in the CMS that are not crashing because they get a **403 Forbidden** error. This happens for example in when the php function `getimagesize()` is used.

```
Warning: getimagesize(http://sub.domain.com/img/image.jpg) 
[function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /path/to/file/sub.domain.com/fpdf.php on line 1350
```

How would I be able to solve this?

Also I would like to know how to redirect everyone who has not IP 1.2.3.4 to http://www.domain.com.

Comment: You’ll also need to allow access from the server your PHP scripts are running from.

Comment: Whenever possible you should prefer to configure such rules inside the server configuration. Using .htaccess style files is error prone, hard to debug and slows down the server considerably.

Comment: @arkascha, I'm not a ICT pro so how would I accomplish that? Logging in with SSH to the server?

Comment: What do mean refer to by the acronym 'ICT'? Apart from that: sure, changing the configuration of your http server usually requires a shell on the system and a privilidged account, so usually root access. Though certainly other setups are possible as well.

Comment: @arkascha, whith ICT I meant IT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology). I have root access to the server, but probably it's better to contact the hosting provider for that (with my knowledge of IT).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `localhost` as well:

```
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
```

Comment: When I also allow access from 127.0.0.1, would that not make the security less secure? Not that the system only rely's on this method of security. But faking ip 127.0.0.1 is very easy. Guessing my company IP is more difficult. Just thinking out loud!

Comment: There's no difference in faking 127.0.0.1 or 1.2.3.4 - at least you must rely on something. And if this is still giving you an error on the php access, elaborate your infrastructure, please. Is the php thingy running on the machine where the CMS is located?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` rule for finer control to redirect users to home page that are outside allowed list of IPs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(1\.2\.3\.4|127\.0\.0\.1)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ http://www.domain.com/? [L,R]
```

I have also added `127.0.0.1` (localhost) and you can add as many internal IPs as you want here in the allowed list.

Comment: Doing exactly this gives me a loop error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: It now redirects me to sub.domain.com. However CSS isn't loaded correctly. So not redirect to www.domain.com but to sub.domain.com

Comment: No, also doesn't work, same result. I'm a bit of a noob in htaccess stuff... sorry!

Comment: What doesn't work? You don't see css/js/images or anything else?

Comment: The script should redirect to http://www.domain.com/ So I changed that in your code. But is still redirects to sub.domain.com. Indeed I don't see any CSS markup, images, colors. Only HTML elements

Comment: can you try updated code now. Also what happens when you directly load `http://www.domain.com/` do you get css/images fine? Also worth trying in a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: loading `http://www.domain.com` works fine. I will try your new code as soon as possible!